# WP7: Why does a ListBox.ItemsPanel break my ElementName data binding?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a Windows Phone 7 `ListBox` that binds to a list of integers.  I am using the default MVVM Light template, so there is a `ViewModel` class that contains data and a simple `RelayCommand`.  Here is the ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                        
            <Button Content="{Binding}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=ContentGrid, Path=DataContext.TestCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This displays a vertical list of integers inside buttons.  If you click any of them, the following command code executes and shows a pop-up: `new RelayCommand<int>(i => MessageBox.Show("Test" + i));`

However, if I simply add the following XAML to change to a horizontal list, the databinding fails.  Nothing happens when you click the button and no error messages are written to the Output window.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

I have tried some other types of binding for the `EventToCommand`.  For example, specifying my `ViewModel` as a static resource.  It works, but is less ideal than the example above.

Why does that `ItemsPanel` break the databinding?

Comment: Someone mentions this problem here: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/213237/503547.aspx Their problem doesn't include MVVM Light and is also specific to WP7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with `Silverlight 3`. To work around this, wrap your `DataTemplate` in a `UserControl`:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication.MyUserControl">
        <Button Content="{Binding}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=ContentGrid, Path=DataContext.TestCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </UserControl>
```

And use it instead:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                        
            <local:MyUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: In MVVM Light, you can also find the VM through the ViewModelLocator. I prefer that personally. The binding becomes {Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main.MyCommand} where Main is the VM that hosts the MyCommand

Comment: @LBugnion: I did not know that. Thanks for the tip. I am familiar with Prism but not MVVM Light. Can you point me to a place/referecne/documentation that would be a good startup for an absolute beginner? For example, for Prism they have a big PDF.