# Problem binding ICommand to event using ElementName within Pivot control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I am trying to hook up an ICommand on the model to a button within the ItemTemplate of a Pivot control.
To get a link to the parent model from within the ItemTemplate I usually use ElementName specifying the Name I provided for the xaml page.

This works when I use a ListBox to contain the items but not a pivot control.

Does any one have any ideas or come across this problem before?

Just noticed that if I define the PivotItems in xaml the Binding works.  So it is only failing when I am dynamically populating the Pivot control.

UPDATE : OK So I'm beat with this now.  I have linked the event to the models ICommand in the views code behind (nasty) and I'm going to look @ this later.  I will post my solution here once I have found it but any help would be great.

Comment: Do you mean for Windows Phone, or desktop Silverlight?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about Windows Phone

Comment: Just noticed that if I define the PivotItems in xaml the Binding works.  So it is only failing when I am dynamically populating the Pivot control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know problem in `Silverlight 3`. Since, `WP7` uses it right now, you will face the same thing with it as well.

To fix that, wrap your `DataTemplate` content that you put in your `ItemTemplate` into a `UserControl`.

Look into this question for further details.

[WP7: Why does a ListBox.ItemsPanel break my ElementName data binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640370/wp7-why-does-a-listbox-itemspanel-break-my-elementname-data-binding/4647285#4647285)

Comment: That did not appear to change anything.  Looking at the problem reported by the other dev they appear to be having problems with the ListBox control but I have successfully done this.