# Binding to an MVVM Light relay command inside of a Windows Phone 7 item data template

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I'm attempting to bind a button to a viewmodel command using MVVM Light commands, and for some reason the command doesn't seem to be getting called. Normally I don't have any issues using commands, but this one seems to be ignoring the binding.

Here's my code:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <Command:EventToCommand 
                            Command="{Binding MyButtonClickAction}" />
                    </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>

            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyOtherProperty}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This data template is in a list that gets created after my app launches, and I'm wondering if that's the problem. My theory is that the view model is created and the constructor attempts to set up the binding with the relay command, but since the list doesn't have any items yet, the binding fails somehow.

The bindings to MyProperty and MyOtherProperty work fine.

Any suggestions as to how I might get this working?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting, Matt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that inside a DataTemplate, the DataContext is the item itself, not your ViewModel. So when you say `{Binding MyButtonActionClick}`, the binding is looking for a command called `MyButtonActionClick` on the *item*, which I'm guessing is just a simple object and doesn't have command properties of its own.

There are a couple of ways to get around this. Since you're already using MMVM Light the best approach might be to define your collection as `List<FooViewModel>` rather than `List<Foo>` and wrap your items in a ViewModel class of their own. Then you can add a `MyButtonActionClick` command to that ViewModel and the call back to the parent ViewModel.

Otherwise, change your command binding so it looks at the DataContext of the ItemsControl itself. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640370/wp7-why-does-a-listbox-itemspanel-break-my-elementname-data-binding) (and the accepted answer, of course) for some ideas on how to do that.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I'm thinking I'll opt for the seperate viewmodel. Thanks!

Comment: In MVVM Light, you can also find the VM through the ViewModelLocator. I prefer that personally. The binding becomes {Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main.MyCommand} where Main is the VM that hosts the MyCommand

Comment: I like the ViewModelLocator approach. You don't actually need to 'install' MVVM Light to get that working. Using this approach in WP7 which has limited binding capabilities.

Answer (score 7):

As a side note, you may want to consider using the ButtonBaseExtensions class when associating commands with your buttons. This class can be found in the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command namespace in the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP7 assembly.

Your namespace XAML would then include :-

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP7"
```

Your button XAML would then look something like this :-

```
<Button cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding MyButtonClickAction}"/>
```

Comment: Wow--had no idea that you could do this. This will cut my XAML files down quite a bit--Thanks!