# WP7: Binding to an element outside pivot.itemtemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, scope, pivot

I've been struggling for a while on this. I'm a bit of a newbie, but i lurked a lot and still couldn't find a solution to my problem, so I decided to post my question here.

I'm binding a pivot to a collection of objects I want to display to create a gallery. Here is my pivot control bound to a list called gallery, where each object contains 2 strings (url and description).

```
<controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding gallery}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="galleryPivot">
            <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding url}" />
                            <Grid Visibility="{Binding ElementName=galleryPivot, Path=DataContext.ShowDetail}">
                                <ListBox>
                                    <ListBoxItem>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                </ListBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot>
```

The datacontext is the viewmodel and initialized in the constructor of the page.
Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class GalleryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Gallery> gallery
    {
        get { return Globals.pictures; }

    }

    private Visibility _showDetail = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility ShowDetail
    {
        get { return _showDetail; }
        set {
           _showDetail = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("ShowDetail");
        }
    }       
    public GalleryViewModel()
    { }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { return; };
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The gallery object is a list in my ViewModel, as the ShowDetail property. As ShowDetail is outside the scope, I tried to set ElementName as explained [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640370/wp7-why-does-a-listbox-itemspanel-break-my-elementname-data-binding)

The pivot binds well to the gallery list, but when I change the value of ShowDetail, the grid won't hide. I also tried to set ElementName to LayoutRoot but it still won't work.

My question, how can I bind the visibility when it is  outside the scope of the itemtemplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a `DataTemplate` the **ElementName** binding refers only to the names of elements that are within that `DataTemplate`. The data context within your data template is the `Gallery` instance, not the `GalleryViewModel`. You could move the **ShowDetail** property down to the `Gallery` class instead.

If you'd rather not do that, then an alternative would be to use a proxy for the data context, which you add as a resource to the page and bind to the page's data context (a `GalleryViewModel` instance presumably). You can then reference that resource as you would any other resource to get at the parent data context.

If you're not familiar with this proxy concept, then [Dan Wahlin's post on the subject](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) should help.

Comment: I'll think I'll go with the proxy approach as the property ShowDetail is a shared property (static). Thanks for answering so fast and clearly!