# Making custom Gallery View for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I ma a newbie to wp7 (and dot net). I have some thumbnails in my application, which on clicked I want to show them open in detail. As there is now default picture viewer available in wp7, I am trying to make one my own (with next, previous and pinch zoom). I am trying to follow [this](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2010/09/easy-windows-phone-7-photo-viewer-using.html) but I have no idea of how to bind the image to the pivot control... please help. Thanks!!!

Comment: Where do you keep your images? In the blog they are kept in a collection (like a List, an Array etc). Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(v=vs.95).aspx) for information on data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [WP7: Binding to an element outside pivot.itemtemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381275/wp7-binding-to-an-element-outside-pivot-itemtemplate)

Though you should consider showing just 3 images in the pivot control, and when turning a page in the control you should remove the last item, and add one new. You have to do this, because it is not recomended to use a pivot control displaying more than 9 items.